# SSI include virtual relative path not working

Tags: include, virtual, ssi

My website is set up to use SSI and it's been working great.

However, when I try to include a file via SSI it won't work for I use a relative path. For example, the following works

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--#include virtual="include/head.shtml" -->
    </head>
</html>
```

But this does not (assume that the files exist)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--#include virtual="../include/head.shtml" -->
    </head>
</html>
```

Is there something I'm missing, or is there a way I can get more information regarding this error.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Apache Tutorial](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html#standard-footer):

> The `include` element can determine what file to include with either the
>   `file` attribute, or the `virtual` attribute. The `file` attribute is a file
>   path, *relative to the current directory*. That means that it cannot be
>   an absolute file path (starting with /), nor can it contain ../ as
>   part of that path. The `virtual` attribute is probably more useful, and
>   should specify a URL relative to the document being served. It can
>   start with a /, but must be on the same server as the file being
>   served.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes#Most_common_directives):

> "`virtual`" specifies the target relative to the domain root, while "`file`" specifies the path relative to the directory of the current file.

Comment: I get this error. The thing that confuses me is .../assets/reference_editable_forms/js path. that file doesn't exist.

[Tue Dec 29 13:28:14 2015] [error] [client ::1] unable to include file "../../include/head.shtml" in parsed file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TO/assets/reference_editable_forms/current_employed.html

[Tue Dec 29 13:28:14 2015] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TO/assets/reference_editable_forms/js, referer: http://localhost:9988/TO/assets/reference_editable_forms/current_employed.html?objectId=LAytov5IZr&applicant_email=myemail%40gmail.com ...

Comment: A full path of "head.shtml" is "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TO/include/head.shtml"?

Comment: Yes. On that machine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Server Side Includes are only processed when a file is loaded from a web server, i.e. when you view the web pages in your browser calling them from a URL (like http://.... ). When viewing your web pages on your desktop, you won´t see the includes.

Font: http://www.easywebtutorials.com/tutorials/ssi.html